# How to reschedule a job in android in case of failure using job scheduler

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am using Job scheduler to complete some task . In case of failure I want to reschedule my job until it gets completed  , how do I achieve that with Job Scheduler ?

Comment: post your existing code

Comment: Without source it is hard to tel,l but I assume at some point you call jobFinished() from inside your JobService implementation. If not, please try doing so. Here you can specify if you need your job being rescheduled.

Answer (score 2):

The JobService method jobFinished() has a needsReschedule parameter. Try calling this method after you received the unrecoverable error.