# Android Oreo - JobScheduler stops after a while

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, android-8.1-oreo

On Oreo, I am facing this issue that the JobScheduler stops around 1:30-2am and does not run at all even in the morning when I start using the phone for other things. The documentation seems to suggest that it is controlled by the OS and it will be run periodically, even if not exact, by the OS based on the phone state. Please let me know why this might be stopping and how to create one that will run periodically. MMy code snippet is below. Appreciate your help.

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) appContext.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(appContext, MyJobService.class);
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        .setPeriodic(900000) //15mins
        .setPersisted(true)
        .build();
jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

Comment: Maybe you can check FirebaseJobDispatcher.

Comment: While I check that, can you please let me know if there is any native method to implement a periodic running feature ?

Comment: In theory that code is okey. I dont know what your problem can be, maybe that the job fails to be launched onced, and it doesnt have any restart strategy or is not set to retry after it failed, so it never launches again. Thats why i recommend FirebaseJobDispatcher, because you can define a strategy, or what to do and when in case it fails, like to try to reschedule it, or wait until next  scheduled launch. And it just works awesome.

Comment: Check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242058/how-to-reschedule-a-job-in-android-in-case-of-failure-using-job-scheduler) to see how to reschedule a normal job with jobScheduler.

Comment: That is the strange part, I had put a logger and I could see that it had logged approx every 15mins for about 2 hours, till 2am and then stopped. I get your point, the Restart strategy is something to think about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178179/discussion-between-krishnan-v-s-and-pra).